# Как изменить список системных события плагина modx?

Tags: modx

MODX Revolution 2.7.3-pl

как из кода плагина или другого php файла изменить список включённых событий плагина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [тут](https://docs.modx.com/current/ru/extending-modx/plugins/system-events#kastomnye-sobytiya) посмотрите документацию, как это сделать программно. Если вкратце - нужно сначала создать событие через API, потом вызвать и "слушать".

Или еще для понимания, как реализуется плагин на событие в minishop2 - [здесь](https://modx.pro/help/3016)